# catkin_ws_top: command not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Creating a ROS package by hand.(ROS Tutorial 1-Intermediate level)

After reading this line:
*This tutorial assumes that we're working your catkin workspace and sourcing of the setup file is already done. *
I executed all tutorial 1-Beginner level and then When I run:

```
catkin_ws_top $ mkdir -p src/foobar
```

The Error is:

**catkin_ws_top: command not found**

Kindly help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/118116/catkin_ws_top:-command-not-found/) by [mudassar](https://answers.ros.org/users/10726/mudassar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2014-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is a display of your command line and probably shows the path you are supposed to be in. The command starts after the $ sign.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mudassar](https://answers.ros.org/users/10726/mudassar/) on 2014-01-15**:
But when we are in catkin workspace the path is catkin_ws. Where is catkin_ws_top?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-01-15**:
When you are in a catkin workspace the path is - whatever you named it. It's just an example.